# HTTP POST header data are not applied using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I my swift app . I want to create a request POST with alamofire

The request

```
$ curl \
          -H 'Accept: application/json' \
          -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          -X POST -d '{ "user": { "email": "user@example.com", "password": "1234" } }' \
          http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

My code

```
    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://lobo-api.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up")!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    let parameters = ["user": ["email": "bolo@me.com", "password": "OPOPO"]]
    var JSONSerializationError: NSError? = nil
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &JSONSerializationError)

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


   Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(error)
             println(response)
             println(data)
            println(error)

    }
```

I have got this error

> Optional( { URL: https://lobo-api.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up } { status code: 404, headers {
>       Connection = "keep-alive";
>       "Content-Length" = 1564;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Sun, 05 Apr 2015 19:54:11 GMT";
>       Server = Cowboy;
>       Via = "1.1 vegur";
>       "X-Request-Id" = "12df8182-c91e-439f-b773-2b2e48f3f0c6";
>       "X-Runtime" = "0.007897";
>   } })
>   nil
>   Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x170678500 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.})

Comment: You probably want your HTTP method to be `POST`, right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all in you **curl** command you use a **POST** request,  but in your code you want to make a **GET** request.

Then you're getting a 404 response from the server. According with **[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)** exact definition, you have a **404 http status code response** which means: *"..The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.."*  (in your case probably because you must do a POST request instead to a GET)

Finally, you see also a **3840 http status code**:
an error that you get each time the server is not responding properly with JSON code and JSON text must be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32 (in your case probably because you must do a POST request instead to a GET)

Answer (score 0):

Your end point `https://lobo-api.herokuapp.com/users/sign_up` is wrong. You're getting a 404 response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's was an issue with heroku. The last update was not actived